# How to customize webform item formats, for the preview page?

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to disable all links targeting entities (taxonomy terms for instance) when previewing a webform, just before submitting it.

When building webforms, I know it's possible to customize how items get displayed on the view page (when viewing a webform submission). This can be achieved by configuring the "Advanced > Submission display" section of an item, like so:
[image: Submission display section of a webform item]

But I can't find how to configure the same thing for the "preview" page that recaps all filled-in fields, just before submitting a webform. Is that configurable? Or do I have to override webforms' templates?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I crossed my wires with Drupal's configuration. It seems the preview page does apply the configuration we set for submissions' display in "Advanced > Submission display".

I guess we could argue configuration could be different for the preview page and the view page, but it suits my needs in my case, so... all good :)